# WPF realtime chart application architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, prism

I have the following scenario in mind:

I want to send (via serial port) some commands to a device. This device does send me back a continuous stream of data (max. 12000 values per second).

To control some settings I need some buttons to send commands to the device to start/stop/change settings before and during data stream. Also I want to have a real time plot of this data. I will filter this data of course. Also at certain timestamps there will be a signal which indicates that I want to cut out a certain window of the received data.

This means I will have two charts. I made already some progress using WPF but now when I interact (zoom/pan) with the lower chart, the upper one freezes noticeable. This is because both have do be refreshed very often!

Work (data receiving/filtering) is done using threads but the update of the plot has to be done within the ui thread.

Any ideas how to solve this issue? Maybe using multiple processes?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use Reactive Extensions.  It was built for this kind of thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

[Requesting a clear, picturesque explanation of Reactive Extensions (RX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033809/requesting-a-clear-picturesque-explanation-of-reactive-extensions-rx?rq=1)

On this second link, although the topic is javascript, much of what it says is about Reactive Extensions and cross-applies to Rx in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a similar WPF application with real-time waveforms (about 500Hz). I have a background threads that receives real-time data, a separate threads to process them and prepare the data for drawing (I have a buffer with the "size" of the screen where I put the prepared values). In the UI thread I draw the waveforms to the **RenderTargetBitmap** which is in the end is rendered to the Canvas. This technique allows me have a lot of real-time waveforms on the screen and have zoom and pan working without any problems (about 40-50 fps).

Please let me know if you need some technical details, I can later share them with you.

I think you have some code in the UI thread that is not optimized well or can be moved to the background thread.

Btw, do you use any framework for charts?

**Edit**

*philologon* is right, you should use Rx for real-time data, it simplifies code A LOT. I also use them in my project.

Comment: I use oxyplot. The only thing I do within the UI thread is to give values to the plot and update it. As far as I know, this has to be done in the UI thread. Also if I do not update the plots, I get high fps. Do you have an example how you draw your waves? Maybe this already gives me some hint how to do things better.

Comment: Sure, I will share some examples tomorrow. As far as I know (and I did a small investigation in this area) oxyplot is not very good for real-time data. Indeed you have not very much choices. http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/ (http://d3future.codeplex.com/) is good, but very outdated. I wouldn't use it in real project, but for the investigations it's very good. You can use [Direct 2D](http://blog.rthand.com/post/2012/01/10/Realtime-graph-for-WPF.aspx). And you always render charts by yourself which is what I do.

Comment: I did also some investigation. I found dynamicdatadisplay, but it is really not up to date. I will have a look at Rx and Direct 2D. Though I would be really interested in your RenderTargetBitmap method. I read already about it but never found a good example. This would be really great. The receiving and processing I do also in different threads. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey MrZoidberg, would be great if you could share an example about zooming and panning of the image. I figured out how to use the InteropBitmap to render my images. But maybe your example would give me some better idea. I also tried using SharpDX but it is far more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Its a commercial product but there is a real-time WPF chart which can handle this use-case and then some. Please take a look at the Tutorial below:

http://www.scichart.com/synchronizing-chartmodifier-mouse-events-across-charts/

[image]

There is a live Silverlight demo of this behaviour here:

[Sync Multichart Mouse Silverlight Demo](http://www.scichart.com/Abt.Controls.SciChart.SL.ExampleTestPage.html#/Abt.Controls.SciChart.Example;component/Examples/IWantTo/ZoomAndPanAChart/SynchronizeMouseAcrossCharts.xaml)

And this chart should be able to handle zooming while inputting values at high speed:

[Realtime Performance Demo](http://www.scichart.com/Abt.Controls.SciChart.SL.ExampleTestPage.html#/Abt.Controls.SciChart.Example;component/Examples/IWantTo/CreateRealtimeChart/RealTimePerformanceDemoView.xaml)

**Disclosure:** I am the owner and tech-lead of SciChart